# Texture2d.SaveAsPng() Memory Leak

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, xna

I have found strange issue with method [Texture2d.SaveAsPng()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.SaveAsPng%29;k%28SaveAsPng%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)
Every call 1.5mb disapear.
I use this method to save texture to isolated storage

```
public static void SaveTextureToISF(string fileName, Texture2D texture)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, file)
                    )
                {
                    texture.SaveAsPng(fileStream, texture.Width, texture.Height);
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

I need to save large amount of textures and i have huge memory leak.
On windows phone 8 devices all works fine, this issue only on windows phone 7.

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory leak, does the app crash if you keep on calling `SaveAsPng`? Also, are you creating the Texture2D specially for this method, or are you using it elsewhere? If you're not using it elsewhere, you mustn't forget to call the `Dispose` method on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by getting texture data in `byte` array and saving it to *Isolated Storage*.

```
public static void SaveTextureToISF(string fileName, Texture2D texture)
{
    byte[] textureData = new byte[4 * texture.Width * texture.Height];
    texture.GetData(textureData);
    Save(fileName, textureData); //saving array to IS
}
```

And when texture is needed, load `byte` array from storage and load this data to new texture.

```
 public static Texture2D LoadTextureFromISF(string fileName, int width, int height)
 {
     Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);
     byte[] textureData = Load(fileName); //load array from IS
     texture.SetData(textureData);
     return texture;
 }
```

One thing to note, when loading texture from storage you should know exactly dimension of saved texture and pass it as parameters in load function. This can be easily modified, but I don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

`Texture2D.SaveAsPng()` has a known memory leak. I noticed this issue quite a while back and found a solution for it. The only solution is to create your own texture saving routine.

```
public static void Save(this Texture2D texture, int width, int height, ImageFormat    imageFormat, string filename)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        byte blue;
        IntPtr safePtr;
        BitmapData bitmapData;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        byte[] textureData = new byte[4 * width * height];

        texture.GetData<byte>(textureData);
        for (int i = 0; i < textureData.Length; i += 4)
        {
            blue = textureData[i];
            textureData[i] = textureData[i + 2];
            textureData[i + 2] = blue;
        }
        bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        safePtr = bitmapData.Scan0;
        Marshal.Copy(textureData, 0, safePtr, textureData.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        bitmap.Save(filename, imageFormat);
    }
}
```

Which you can then call as (provided you keep it as an extension method) `texture.SaveAs(texture.Width, texture.Height, ImageFormat.Png, fileName);`

Comment: i got error `Error: The base class or interface 'System.MarshalByRefObject' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Drawing.Image' could not be resolved c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll` when try to compile project, but there is no visible errors in code editor.

Comment: Hmm, Might want to ask that elsewhere :/ I'm not really sure but it sounds like an issue with the reference to System.Drawing

Comment: `System.Drawing` not avaible on windows phone platform. There is no chance to compile this code.

Comment: @Feusp: Oh, didn't realize that. In that case I'm really not sure what to do for this issue.