# How correctly to save texture2d to MediaLibrary wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

The problem is in method [Texture2D.SaveAsPng](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.saveaspng.aspx). I recently found out [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248018/texture2d-saveaspng-memory-leak) in this method in similar problem but managed to solve it. But I can't fit that solution here. What I'm trying now is:

```
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pic.SaveAsJpeg(ms, pic.Width, pic.Height);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        library.SavePicture(path, ms);
        ms.Close();
```

And, every call I lose about 4mb of memory (texture dimension 800x620).
I have tried to create `MemoryStream` from byte array but it throws `Value does not fall within the expected range` exception.

```
        byte[] textureData = new byte[4 * picHeight * picWidth];
        pic.GetData(textureData);
        library.SavePicture(path, textureData); //exception on this line
```

So, I guess, I need to convert `Texture2D` in byte array so that `library.SavePicture(path, ms)` won't throw exception, but I have no clue how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** memory leak in `Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg` occurs only on windows phone 7.

**Upd:** Memory stream length created from byte array from `Texture.GetData` is 1984000, when length of memory stream from  `Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg` is 141520.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you copied texture `pic` data in `textureData` but you never use it.
Maybe you need to do:

```
byte[] textureData = new byte[4 * picHeight * picWidth];
pic.GetData(textureData);
library.SavePicture(path, textureData);
```

**UPDATE**

According to MSDN for `MediaLibrary.SavePicture`:

> Image data that is passed in must be in a JPEG file format.
>   Additionally, SavePicture always saves the image in a JPEG file
>   format.

It seems that the `byte[]` that you get from `Texture2D.GetData` is not in that format, but I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: Bad copy paste, sorry. I tried to pass byte array like you suggest, memory stream created from that byte array but it didnt work, exeption is thrown on save line.

Comment: Why has your byte array from Texture.GetData a length of 1984000? If the texture is 800x420 shouldn't it be 1344000?

Comment: i failed again, exact dimension 800x620 instead of 800x420. I feel kinda awkward now.